# Best way to fetch JSON from web server, with input parameters

Tags: ios, objective-c, json

I'm developing an application for a business and I have to connect to their web server to download data in JSON format. I have to do it in Objective-c.

More specifically, i have to make a POST request and i need to enter username and password by sending this JSON string as input:

```
{\"user\":\"username\",\"pwd\":\"password\"}
```

Next, I have to download a JSON file.

What is the easiest way?

I've tried with:

```
NSString *user = @"foo";
NSString *pwd = @"bar";   
NSString *jsonRequest = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"{\"user\":\"%@\",\"pwd\":\"%@\"}",user,pwd];
NSLog(@"Request: %@", jsonRequest);

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"url"];

NSMutableURLRequest *request = [[NSMutableURLRequest alloc] initWithURL:url];
NSData *requestData = [NSData dataWithBytes:[jsonRequest UTF8String] length:[jsonRequest length]];

[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Accept"];
[request setValue:@"application/json" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
[request setValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%lu", (unsigned long)[requestData length]] forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
[request setHTTPBody: requestData];
NSLog(@"%@", requestData);
```

But if I try to print requestData, nothing happens. I do not download anything and the terminal remains blank. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. The usual way is using `NSURL(Request)`, `NSURLSession`, `NSURLSessionDataTask`, `NSJSONSerialization`. There are countless examples here on SO.

Comment: You should use `[jsonRequest dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];` rather than `dataWithBytes` but you might serialize the JSON with `NSJSONSerialization`

Comment: @vadian ok, now I try! I've another `little` problem. If i write `NSLOG(@"test")` in viewDidLoad or viewWillAppear, the console does not print anything. I think I have a problem in the terminal, what could it be?

Comment: That's a new question. Check if the console in Xcode is visible (⇧⌘C). Maybe only the debug area is visible.

Comment: @vadian ok, i've solved the terminal problem and I have changed `dataWithBytes` with `NSData *requestData = [jsonRequest dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];` and next I've write     `NSArray *jsonArray = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:requestData options: NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error: &e];`...but nothing has changed..